# Dedicated database server setup. Where should my Sphinx and Thinking Sphinx configurations/indices go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Using Rails 3.2, Thinking Sphinx 3.0.6, Sphinx 2.2.4-id64-beta.

I am setting up a dedicated database server for my app. May I know the following:

1. Where should I install Sphinx? App server or database server?
2. Is the following `/path/to/app/server/current/config/thinking_sphinx.yml` correct:

   `address: database_server_ip_address
   pid_file: /path/to/app/server/shared/pids/searchd.pid
   indices_location: /path/to/app/server/shared/db/sphinx
   configuration_file: /path/to/app/server/shared/config/production.sphinx.conf`

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @blelump Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably depends on where you want to avoid latency. If it's on the database server, then indexing will be fast, but search queries may be a bit slow (granted, they're just facing the same hit that database queries are, so I'd hope that was negligible either way). If indexing's not too hard and you want that extra touch of speed, then having Sphinx on your web server might be better.

That said, you're more likely to scale up the number of web servers, so having a single Sphinx daemon on the database server is probably the better way to go.

As for the options - they look correct (the paths are outside of the `current` directory or any specific release). You'll just want to make sure the actual directories exist.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the setup that you are suggesting is installing Sphinx on the database server only, the TS configuration is correct. There is also an `address` option in the TS configuration, what should I put? The indexing can be compromised since I am using realtime indexes, but searching should be fast. Do you have any example setup configurations that I can refer to?

Comment: Ah, for the address, you want the IP address of wherever Sphinx is hosted (so, your suggestion of the db server is correct, if that's where Sphinx is installed).

Comment: Beyond what's in the documentation for deployment, no, I'm afraid I don't have other sources I can point to.